# IIS7 SSL Wildcard Certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

Will a wildcard certificate work with a domain and a subdomain?

`http://example.com` 
`http://sub.example.com`

Can I setup a wildcard certificate to be used by these two? In the tutorials I have followed, they always use two or more subdomains without the main domain (tutorials [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2010/12/27/setting-up-a-wildcard-certificate-in-iis-7-how-to-avoid-those-certificate-mismatch-errors.aspx))

Comment: This would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes.

If you configure ***.helpme.com**, you can secure

- www.helpme.com
- photos.helpme.com
- blog.helpme.com etc

The wildcard certificate will only secures the level of subdomain you specify. So for example, if a certificate is configured for *.www.helpme.com, it will not secure www.helpme.com.

Comment: This is why a typical wildcard certificate issued to `example.com` would include two names, `*.example.com` *and* `example.com`.